# KDE Plasma does not apply global font settings in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fonts, plasma

[Fonts and the icons on bottom right are extra small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCQ29.jpg)

[Somehow even the icons of my folders changed and the same small fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbqUU.jpg)

I got today my new 42" monitor and although the resolution is fine, the font sizes are inhumanly small. When I try to change back to my elder monitor with the same resolution where stuff was readable does not help anymore, it still remains small. And somehow the icons of plasma (e.g. of the folders but not all as you can see) changed. And the icons' sizes in the bottom panel and the folder menu are also small.

If you need any input tell me.

[My global settings which do not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLq91.jpg)

Comment: I've been having this problem with my kubuntu 16.04 servers for over 6 months now and I haven't been able to find a way to make font sizes consistent. Login screen and certain dialogs show too small to be read, some fonts on the system settings are too large and there are buttons that cannot be accesed

Comment: coincidentally, I also happen to have a 42" monitor

Comment: @lurscher  the thing is, that when I just unplugged the 42" and plugged in my old monitor, it didn't help either. What "helped" though or at least partially solved to problem, was a dist-upgrade. Now under 17.04 the icons, the bar in the bottom and the folders are human readable BUT the font size in some applications (eg. GIMP) are still unreadably small.

Comment: @lurscher a complete reinstall "did" the full job.